# Charged black holes selective eaters

Tags: black-hole, celestial-mechanics

We have a charged black hole which is negatively charged. For this simple case the black hole is not rotating.

If a negatively charged particle approaches the singularity the electromagnetic repulsion will become stronger than the gravitational attraction causing the object to leave the black hole? But how is that even possible .

There is only one spacetime path available for every object beyond the event horizon and what would this object experience?

Could it travel into the future and into the past after oscillating inside the black hole?

Comment: Now I'm curious what the critical q/m ratio is for a black hole to become "unattractive" to electrons, or to protons!

Comment: There's a xkcd that's related.  https://what-if.xkcd.com/140/  "The Reissner-Nordström equations compare the outward force of the charge to the inward pull of gravity. If the outward push from the charge is large enough, it's possible the event horizon surrounding the black hole can disappear completely. That would leave behind an infinitely-dense object from which light can escape—a naked singularity."

Comment: How will the destruction of the event horizon affect the surroundings?